# Calibrating Heston model parameters using the Active-set method and Levenberg–Marquardt

Tags: options, volatility, calibration, heston

**Background**: We're estimating the parameters of the Heston model from current market data of options. This is to be implemented using the active-set method (see section 16.5 [here](https://pages.mtu.edu/~struther/Courses/OLD/Sp2013/5630/Jorge_Nocedal_Numerical_optimization_267490.pdf)) and the Levenberg-Marquardt method (see [here](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0377221717304460)). The resulting optimization problem is a least squares problem (the same as that used in the Heston article, equation number (4)), subject to the Feller condition $2 \kappa \eta - \theta^2 > 0$ as an additional condition by us. The solving algorithm will be executed for multiple starting points to determine a set of local optima of the Heston model.

We fail to understand the conditions used for the active sets, as the article referenced for Levenberg-Marquardt states the optimization problem is chosen to be unconstrained. With the Feller condition being a strict inequality, it will not be used in an active set.

**Our understanding**: We're assuming to use the LM method to solve a sub-problem given by the active-set method. However, without any (non-strict) inequality conditions we fail to understand how our sub-problems will be formed.

Are we able to alter the strict inequality of the Feller condition by adding a slack variable? Say, to allow for a slack of magnitude $10^{-10}$.

If so, if the condition can be made active, how would the LM method be adapted to account for this condition? If not, are we missing something entirely?

Answer (score 1):

From the point of view of reasonable Heston model calibrations, coming even *close* to violating the Feller condition provides *very* unrealistic forward volatility surfaces.  Therefore, you should feel perfectly comfortable enforcing $2 \kappa \eta - \theta^2 \geq \epsilon$ for some fairly nontrivial $\epsilon$.

The authors of your linked paper do not mention how they treat inequality constraints.  They write that they used [LEVMAR](http://users.ics.forth.gr/~lourakis/levmar/) as their Levenberg-Marquardt solver, which has a variant allowing for such constraints, but it's also possible they ran unconstrained and then rejected any local minima that violated the Feller condition.  That's a common approach.

Since the Levenberg-Marquardt algorithm is basically an interpolation between gradient descent and Gauss-Newton, the treatment of constraints is fairly well understood, but its always faster to just run without them.